Customize Messages Sent to Slack via EventBridge and SNS
Goal:

Customize messages sent from EventBridge/SNS to Slack

Overview:

I'm sending messages to a Slack channel by using some EventBridge rules that target an SNS topic which has the Slack Chatbot subscribed to it.

This works just fine, and will send messages, however, they are in the default format coming from the source (in my case, some from CloudWatch alerts, some from AWS Config rules). However, I'd like to use Input Transformer to customize the messages (change content, formatting, etc.).
I know it's possible to do this with Lambda, but I think that would require setting up a Lambda for every rule, so ideally I could do this with an Input Transformer template.
Is this even possible, and if so, does anyone have examples of Input Transformer templates for Slack destinations?

You can create custom notifications with AWS Chatbot, which allows some, but not full, customization.
You could create a custom notification for files uploaded to S3 like so:
Input path:
{
  "bucket": "$.detail.bucket.name",
  "detail-type": "$.detail-type",
  "object": "$.detail.object.key",
  "requester": "$.detail.requester"
}

Input template:
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "source": "custom",
  "content": {
  "description": ":large_orange_square: *<detail-type>*\n*<bucket>* <object>"
  }
}

